# Modal Dialog in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog

I need a truly modal dialog to run in Google Chrome in Windows using extension, where the dialog doesn't allow users to click on other tabs etc.  The search results so far seem to suggest that `showModalDialog()` doesn't give a true modal dialog, and the jQuery examples (like SimpleModal) don't seem to be able to stop users from accessing the other tabs or the other parts of the browser.

Alerts seem to be be working, so I was wondering if there is any other solution to this problem?  Or do I really need to write a modal dialog from scratch using Javascript?

Using the hidden div methods in the web pages is not an option because I can't modify them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the native javascript function [confirm](http://cse.csusb.edu/turner/wiki/Javascript_Alert,_Confirm_and_Prompt)
But I don't like when I can't do what I want without good reasons. 
Furthermore, the user will can always switch to another Chrome window.

Comment: The modal dialog needs to be customized, so I can't use alert or confirm as it is.

Comment: may be possible using a content script load on every pages which switches to the desired window. This window should also contains a customized html dialog.

Answer (score 0):

No sort of in tab HTML modal dialog will prevent a user from switching tabs. Even `alert` will allow users to switch tabs. You may be able to achieve this through a [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) though.

Comment: I meant launching it from the extension.  I thought that alert was modal if launched from the extension (from a quick experiment), but I might have mistaken.

Comment: I just created an `alert` from a background page and it would stay in front but I could still switch tabs.

Comment: What I did was to execute a .js file from the background page and then run the alert from that javascript file.  This method seems to prevent the tabs switching somehow.

Comment: I should have specified that I am using Windows.  Will edit the initial post.  I'm not sure if this behavior differs by OS though.